# How to create class by using XSD and SoapObject in android app?

Tags: android, class, xsd

I have a XSD file in that it contain a class "Person" so how can i create this person class in android app using soap object in order to sent this class object in a service call like:

```
SoapObject obj= new SoapObject("namespace","methodname");
obj.addProperty("per",person); 
//where person is the Person class object derived from XSD using soap object
```

so how can i do this conversation plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think `envelope.getResponse()` can return a SoapObject, or a SoapPrimitive/Vector, I think you're casting a Vector on a SoapObject.

Comment: ya i'm using ksoap2 library only, see my code SoapObject openOrder=new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "Person");
     openOrder.addProperty("Name", "SIVA");
     openOrder.addProperty("Address", "HYD");
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);     
     PropertyInfo pInfo=new PropertyInfo();
     pInfo.setName("Id");
     pInfo.setValue(bundle.getString("ID"));
     request.addProperty(pInfo);
     
     request.addProperty("per",person.getClass());

Comment: so what is the problem then can you please elaborate?

Comment: the problem is to get the class from xsd file, see i've a xsd from "xyz.com/abc.svc?xsd=xsd3" so in that i've a class Person in xsd format so how can i get Person object using soap object from that link?

Comment: Or how to get the classes from xsd in order to use in android app.